# Stripe API using cURL and PHP - Unable to get subscriptions or payments by created dates

Tags: php, curl, stripe-payments

Here's the code. Tried several variations of params. Any input would be great.

```
$endpoint = "https://api.stripe.com/v1/payments";
$params = array('limit' => '100', 'created[gte]' => '1627831313');


$url = $endpoint . '?' . http_build_query($params);
$ch = curl_init();

$headr = array();
$headr[] = 'Content-length: 0';
$headr[] = 'Content-type: application/json';
$headr[] = 'Authorization: Bearer [OUR STRIPE KEY]';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headr);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
$result=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Here's the response we get:

```sh
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/payments -u [OUR STRIPE KEY]: -d limit=3  -d created=1627831313  -G 
{
  "error": {
    "code": "parameter_unknown",
    "doc_url": "https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/parameter-unknown",
    "message": "Received unknown parameter: created",
    "param": "created",
    "type": "invalid_request_error"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Silly question, are you just forgetting to write the `$result` somewhere to look at? Are you getting an empty response, or encountering an error?

**Update**: I think this is because you're calling the `/payments` endpoint, which is not what you want here. Change that path to `/payment_intents` ([API ref](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/list?lang=curl)). To get [customers](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/list?lang=curl), [subscriptions](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/list?lang=curl) and [invoices](https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/list?lang=curl) you'd need to make separate calls to each of those endpoints.

Comment: Here's the response we get:
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/payments -u [OUR STRIPE KEY]: -d limit=3  -d created=1627831313  -G 
{
  "error": {
    "code": "parameter_unknown",
    "doc_url": "https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/parameter-unknown",
    "message": "Received unknown parameter: created",
    "param": "created",
    "type": "invalid_request_error"
  }
}

Comment: Oh, I think you might be request the wrong endpoint. What data are you looking for? Probably you actually want `/payment_intents` here.

Comment: Our goal is to import all subscriptions, customers, invoices and payments into our database via the API.

Comment: Updated my answer. You need to make separate calls for those. TO get the payments you'd call `/payment_intents` as I mentioned.